# Problem using git merge in a Jenkins pipeline job in a docker container

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm making a Jenkins job which merges one branch into another, then runs a build on the created commit. I get the error:

```
+ git config --global user.email myemail@gmail.com
error: could not lock config file //.gitconfig: Permission denied
+ git config --global user.name 'Merge before testing'
error: could not lock config file //.gitconfig: Permission denied
+ git merge origin/branchToTest
```

when preparing to merge.

As you see in the error message, there is no folder after the first slash, where it's supposed to be the name of the user, in my case /jenkins/.gitconfig

When I inserted the line `whoami`, I get an error: `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1000`

When I run `docker exec containerName whoami`, it returns `jenkins`

I ensured that the user `jenkins` exists when creating the image. Here's part of the dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
ENV TZ=Asia/Tokyo
USER jenkins
RUN <user stuff>
USER root
RUN <root stuff>
USER jenkins
```

and here's the relevant part of my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
git checkout -B origin/$BASE_BRANCH
git config --global user.email "email@domain"
git config --global user.name "Merge before testing"
git merge origin/$SOURCE_BRANCH
```

Also, I'm quite sure that the merge is failing because the git hashes, retrieved using `git rev-parse --verify HEAD`, do not change before and after `git merge`

In the end, what I'd like is to be able to merge $SOURCE_BRANCH into $BASE_BRANCH using `git merge`, test that merge commit, then revert the merge commit. Using descriptive pipelines and plugins for this purpose is not an option because I'd like to put all steps in code, as much as possible.

Comment: Try `git -c user.email="email@domain" -c user.name="Merge before testing" merge origin /$SOURCE_BRANCH` instead.

Comment: Regarding your permission errors, the part of the `Jenkinsfile` where the build-container is started would be interesting. If for example [withDockerContainer](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/docker-workflow/#withdockercontainer-run-build-steps-inside-a-docker-container) is used, it will automatically switch to the current host jenkins userid/groupid (docker's `-u` flag).